# Prevent AngularJS to return promise with cached data

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm using a service in order to share data between controllers. However, the service is returning a promise with cached data even when making new requests. Depending on where the `defer` instance is created either live data is returned but two-way binding breaks or the two-way binding works but cached data is returned.

How can one prevent the return of a promise with cached data and keep two-way binding?

I've put up a plunker to illustrate the case: http://plnkr.co/edit/SyBvUu?p=preview and for sake of completeness, here is the troublemaking service:

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $q) {

    // When instancing deferred here two way binding works but cached data is returned
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    this.get = function(userId) {
        // When instancing deferred here two way binding breaks but live data is returned
        //var deferred = $q.defer();

        console.log('Fetch data again using id ', userId);
        var url = userId + '.json';
        $http.get(url, {timeout: 30000, cache: false})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data, status, headers, config);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

});
```

UPDATE: The problem wasn't that data was cached, it was that I hadn't understood how a data was to be shared and that the shared data can not be a primitive. See my own answer below.

Comment: Hmm, just for the sport - does it happen if you do `var url = userId+".json?cacheBreaker="+Date.now();` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that path earlier to no avail. When making a request for the different json-files the response returned contains the expected user data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $http returns a deferred object what you are doing here is actually overkill. When I changed your service to the following it seems to work fine.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6KKcCJ?p=preview)

```
app.service('myService', function($http, $q) {

    this.get = function(userId) {
        console.log('Fetch data again using id ', userId);
        var url = userId + '.json';

        return $http.get(url, {timeout: 30000, cache: false});
    };

});
```

**Edit**

To get your controller `SecondCtrl` to update, the easiest thing to do, while keeping the structure of your code the same, is to broadcast the new data in an event defined in `FirstCtrl` using `$rootScope.$broadcast` and capture the broadcasted event in your other controller using `$scope.$on`. I've updated the Plunker and now your data is in sync.

Modified `loadUserFromMyService` function in `FirstCtrl`:

```
$scope.loadUserFromMyService = function(userId) {
    var promise = myService.get(userId);
    promise.then(
      function(data) { 
        console.log('UserData', data);
        $scope.data = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('newData', data);  
      },
      function(reason) { console.log('Error: ' + reason); }
    );      
};
```

Added in `SecondCtrl`:

```
$scope.$on('newData', function (evt, args) {
  console.log('dataChanged', args);
  $scope.data = args;
});
```

Comment: Hi Roy! Unfortunately, the two-binding doesn't work then. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how databinding works. Give me a few minutes to update my answer to explain in better detail.

Comment: Hey @JohnP, sorry that took so long. I've updated my answer. Now your data is in sync.

Comment: thanks for your effort. While looking for an answer I found a site describing some methods for sharing data between controllers and the third alternative seemed like the way to go. And it is actually the same solution as you propose - use broadcast and on.   http://www.ramandv.com/blog/angular-js-sharing-data/

Comment: I came up with another solution, see below, so that one doesn't have to use $broadcast and $on. It feels a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with simplified solution to share data with the help of Luke Kende. Here is a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/JPg1XE?p=preview. See code below.

One important thing is that the shared object isn't a primitive. When I tried different solutions I started with declaring the shared object and assign it `null`, which is a no-no. Using an empty object makes it work.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

// Service
app.service('myService', function($http, $q) {

    //object that will be shared between controllers
    var serviceData = {
        items: []
    };

    return {
      data: serviceData, //pass through reference to object - do not use primitives else data won't update
      get: function(url, overwrite) {
          if (serviceData.items.length === 0 || overwrite){
              $http.get(url, {timeout: 30000})
                  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    //could extend instead of ovewritting
                    serviceData.items = data;
                  })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      serviceData.items = {status: status};
                  });
          }
          return serviceData;
      },
      empty: function(){
          serviceData.items = [];
      },
      more: function(){
          //do some other operations on the data
      }
    };
});

// Controller 1
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {

    //myService.data is not initialized from server yet
    //this way don't have to always use .then() statements
    $scope.data = myService.data; 

    $scope.getTest = function(id){
        myService.get('test' + id + '.json',true);
    };
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.data.items.push({'title': 'Test ' + $scope.data.items.length});
    };
    $scope.delItem = function() {
        $scope.data.items.splice(0,1);
    };

});

// Controller 2
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {

    //just attach myService.data and go
    //calling myService.get() results in same thing
    $scope.data = myService.data;

    //update the the data from second url -
    $scope.getTest = function(id){
        myService.get('test' + id + '.json',true);
    };

    $scope.empty = function(){
       myService.empty();
    };
});
```